# SAP UI5 application Consuming Odata on NW Server - Testing

Tags: odata, same-origin-policy, sapui5

I have developed SAP UI5 application on Eclipse which consumes data using Odata service developed in SAP NW.

First I found problem related to SOP I resolved it by testing it in Chrome by disabling web security and I can see data with out any problems. I did not use any proxy related configuration in web.xml

Now the real problem I deployed this on the SAP NW server and tried testing it, I was expecting that now it is on Server it will run without any problems (I mean I need not switch off security settings as I did before).

My question is there any configuration required to avoid SOP problems for the application which is already on Server?

I have gone through so many posts on this, I could not proper solution.

Comment: What's your detailed problems when you deployed your application in NW server?

Comment: Below are the error messages am getting:

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)                                                       XMLHttpRequest cannot load <<url here>> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin <<hostname here> is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Hi, what kind of resource request is being fired with 401 response? Could you please copy the request too?

Comment: http://hostname:1080/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_ONLFRM_SRV/$metadata   this is the name of Odata service created in SAP NW Gateway builder and it is called in the Init() of application like below

Comment: oDataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(<<above url>, true,"user name", "password"); // OData Model

Comment: Is the hostname the same as the hostname of your application?